# Rectangle cannot be cast to Circle?

Tags: java, object, casting, dynamic-arrays

so I'm trying to write a method that will return the index of the object with the largest area. Here is my current method

```
private static int findPositionLargestObject(ArrayList < GeometricObject > geoList) {
    int maxIndexC = 0;
    int maxIndexR = 0;
    for (GeometricObject o: geoList) {
        for (int i = 1; i < geoList.size(); i++) {
            if (o instanceof Rectangle) {
                if (((Rectangle) geoList.get(i)).getArea() > ((Rectangle) geoList.get(maxIndexR)).getArea()) {
                    maxIndexR = i;
                }
            }
            if (o instanceof Circle) {
                if (((Circle) geoList.get(i)).getArea() > ((Circle) geoList.get(maxIndexC)).getArea()) {
                    maxIndexC = i;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    if (maxIndexC > maxIndexR) {
        return maxIndexC;
    } else return maxIndexR;
}
```

However, when i run this method, I recieve the error message rectangle can't be cast to circle. My reason for having two different if statements is because the getArea methods are different for the circle and rectangle objects respectively. Any ideas why I'm receiving this message, thanks!

Here is my public class

```
public class hw2redo 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

          GeometricObject g = null;
          File diskFile = new File("file.txt");
          Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(diskFile);
          ArrayList<GeometricObject> list = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();
          while(diskScanner.hasNext()){
              String geolist = diskScanner.nextLine();
              g = recreateObject(geolist);

              list.add(g);

          }
          diskScanner.close();
         /* while (diskScanner.hasNext()) {
              String list = diskScanner.nextLine();
              g = recreateObject(list);
          }
          diskScanner.close();*/
          showObjects(list);
          findPositionLargestObject(list);
       }





    private static GeometricObject recreateObject(String data) {

          String[] list = data.split(",");
          String geoObject = list[0];

          if (geoObject.equals("Circle")) {
             String color = list[1];
             boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(list[2]); 
             double radius = Double.valueOf(list[3]);
             return new Circle(radius, color, filled);
          }

          if (geoObject.equals("Rectangle")) {
             String color = list[1];
             boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(list[2]);
             double height = Double.valueOf(list[3]);
             double width = Double.valueOf(list[4]);
             return new Rectangle(width, height, color, filled);
          }
        return null;


       }

    private static void showObjects(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list) {

         for(GeometricObject o : list) {

             if ( o instanceof Circle)
             {
             System.out.println(o);
             ((Circle) o).printCircle();
             System.out.println("");
             }
             if ( o instanceof Rectangle)
             {
             System.out.println(o);
             ((Rectangle) o).printRectangle();
             System.out.println("");
             }
         }
    }
      private static int findPositionLargestObject(ArrayList<GeometricObject> geoList) {

            int maxIndexC = 0;
            int maxIndexR = 0;
            for(GeometricObject o : geoList)
            {
            for (int i = 1; i < geoList.size(); i++) {
                if ( o instanceof Rectangle)
                {
                if (((Rectangle) geoList.get(i)).getArea() > ((Rectangle) geoList.get(maxIndexR)).getArea()) {
                    maxIndexR = i;
                }
                }
                if ( o instanceof Circle)
                {
                if (((Circle) geoList.get(i)).getArea() > ((Circle) geoList.get(maxIndexC)).getArea()) {
                        maxIndexC = i;
                }
                }

            }
        }
           if (maxIndexC > maxIndexR)
           {
               return maxIndexC;
           }
           else
               return maxIndexR;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looping through your array twice for every object.

```
for (GeometricObject o: geoList) { // for each GeometricObject in geoList, 
    for (int i = 1; i < geoList.size(); i++) { // loop through each object in geoList.
```

Remove either the for-each loop or the regular for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no code provided for `GeometricObject`, but i assume that `getArea()` is defined in some way in `GeometricObject`, so why even use a cast, if you can simply evaluate it directly:

```
int max_circle , area_circle;
int max_rect , area_rec;

for(int i = 0 ; i < geoList.size() ; i++){
    GeometricObject go = geoList.get(i);

    if(go instanceof Rectangle)
        if(go.getArea() > area_rec){
            area_rec = go.getArea();
            max_rect = i;
        }else{
            area_circle = go.getArea();
            max_circle = i;
        }
}
```

The reason why your code throws the exception is:

```
((Rectangle) geoList.get(maxIndexR))
```

with `maxIndexR` initialized to 0, and the same for circles. Thus, if the first element in `geoList` is a `Rectangle`, the first circle will cause a call to `((Circle) geoList.get(0))`, but the first element is a `Rectangle`. The same applies the other way. If you want to keep your code, just add another variable for storing the maximum-areas of both circles and rectangles and simply use the values (initialized to 0) instead of retrieving the shape from the list and casting it.

Comment: My GeometricObject actually does not have  getArea() method. My reasoning for that was how would it know whether to retrieve the circle or rectangles area because they require differrent formulas?

Comment: @RiFFRAFF that can be solved pretty simple using abstract methods (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). Though you can simply use the second solution aswell, if you don't want to modify the code of `GeometricObject`.

Comment: Well my GeometricObject class is abstract and my Circle and Rectangle class extend it, I still don't see how i would be able to tell my GeometricObject's getArea method which one I'm trying to use.

Comment: @RiFFRAFF not at all. That's the idea behind polymorphism. You just add an abstract definition to `GeometricObject` and any nonabstract subclass **must** implement `getArea()`. Thus you can do something like: `GeometricObject go = new Rectangle(...); int area = go.getArea();`

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether `o` is an instance of `Rectangle`/`Circle`, but casting `geoList.get(i)` to the corresponding type instead. In fact, `o` isn't used anywhere in the loop except for `instanceof` checks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand, you would have two classes, Rectangle and Circle extending from some common class called Geometry at your end. One important thing to note here is that Rectangle and Circle would be siblings. That is a Rectangle is never a Circle and viceversa. Direct consequence of this statement is that you cannot treat a Rectangle instance as if it were a Circle instance and viceversa.

In your method `findPositionLargestObject` you have `maxIndexC` and `maxIndexR` initialized to 0. While this sounds harmless, down the line you do something like this:

```
            if ( o instanceof Rectangle)
            {
            if (((Rectangle) geoList.get(i)).getArea() > ((Rectangle) geoList.get(maxIndexR)).getArea()) {
```

// What is the guarantee that maxIndexR, which is '0' initially, holds a Rectangle and not a Circle?.
                    maxIndexR = i;
                }
                }
                if ( o instanceof Circle)
                {
                if (((Circle) geoList.get(i)).getArea() > ((Circle) geoList.get(maxIndexC)).getArea()) {
// What is the guarantee that maxIndexC, which is '0' initially, holds a Circle and not a Rectangle?.
                        maxIndexC = i;
                }
                }

Surely there is some fallacy there. Also, if you only have two kinds of Geometry, you can use `if else` instead of two `if clauses`. That would be more error proof.